# Where can i find custom opengl datatypes in SharpGL?

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics

I'm using SharpGL to program OpenGL using C# , but i can't find OpenGL data types just like GLfloat ,GLint, ...... etc

Comment: Why do you need them? You're using C#; use C# types.

Comment: Yes you are right , but i thought those types are special for graphics .

Comment: Not needed -- the examples use the standard types also. If you really wanted, you could use aliasing: `using GLFloat = System.Single;`

Comment: @BlzOfHK: OpenGL has those types because C and C++ do not guarantee the size of particular objects. By using defined types, there is an understanding of how big data are between the particular OpenGL implementation and the user. You don't have that problem in C#; they define the size of all of their types.

Answer (score 1):

I would use OpenGL types anyways. In case you want to use `Byte` or `Bool` for `GLboolean` you change them all with a single line edit. I use this list (not sure if it's complete but it's a start):

```
using GLbitfield = System.UInt32;
using GLboolean = System.Boolean;
using GLbyte = System.SByte;
using GLclampf = System.Single;
using GLdouble = System.Double;
using GLenum = System.UInt32;
using GLfloat = System.Single;
using GLint = System.Int32;
using GLshort = System.Int16;
using GLsizei = System.Int32;
using GLubyte = System.Byte;
using GLuint = System.UInt32;
using GLushort = System.UInt16;
using GLvoid = System.IntPtr;
```